# I found ways to plot a graph in R using plot function. but I am looking to create plot with part of the data

Tags: r, plot, subset

I am trying to plot a graph for a data containing years between 1900 and 2010 and output in each month of the year in R. I need to select years between 1950-2001 against months of Nov-february. How can I select part of data for plotting this graph ? 
since I am a rookie at R programming or any programming, an easy to follow example would be of great help.

thanks
GRV

Comment: Please read [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: check the function `subset`, and notice that `plot` can use a `subset` argument that works in the same way as said function. also, follow zero323's advice.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! You are much more likely to receive a helpful answer if you show what you have tried, explain why your attempts didn't work, and clearly describe your desired results/outputs. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you mean by

> select years between 1950-2001 against months of Nov-february

But the following should get you started on a reproducible example...

```
#create a vector of months from 1900 through 2010
months <- seq(as.Date("1900/1/1"), as.Date("2010/12/31"), "months")
#assign a random vector of equal length
output <- rnorm(length(months))
#assign both values to a data_frame
data <- data.frame(months = months, output = output)
```

Based on your description, your data should look something like the dataframe, called `data`.

From here, you can make use of the `subset` function to help you on your way. The first example subsets to data from 1950 through 2001. The next further restricts that subset to the months of November through February.

```
#subset to just 1950 through 2001
data_sub <- subset(data, months >= as.Date("1950-01-01") & months <= as.Date("2001-12-31"))
#subset the 1950 to 2001 data to just Nov-feb months (i.e. c(11,12,1,2))
data_sub_nf <- subset(data_sub, as.numeric(format(data_sub$months, "%m")) %in% c(11,12,1,2))
```

You should also read [Why is `[` better than `subset`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset) to move beyond `subset`.

As stated, after the data has been subset, you can use `plot` or any other plotting function to graph your data.

Comment: Thank you very much @Joemienko . I followed following method to create subsets Nov<-as.numeric(snow$Nov)
     
     Dec<-as.numeric(snow$Dec)
     
     Jan<-as.numeric(snow$Jan)
     
     Feb<-as.numeric(snow$Feb)
     
     Mar<-as.numeric(snow$Mar)
     
     month<-cbind(Nov,Dec,Jan,Feb,Mar)
     
     year<-as.numeric(substr(snow$Season,1,4))
     
     data<-as.data.frame(cbind(year,month))
     
     data<-data[order(data$year,decreasing=TRUE),]
     
     data1<-subset(data,(year>=1950 & year<=2001),select=c(year,Nov,Dec,Jan,Feb,Mar))

Comment: You are quite welcome! Would you kindly accept the answer if it was helpful?